# I was filing one form, there is an sql error, can you please explain it to me. Why is it showing, layman here

Tags: sql-server

Following is the error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[SqlException (0x80131904): String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +3318656
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +334
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4289
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted) +514
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) +3392
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) +725
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) +551
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +391
   Bcdverfication.froma_2.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\Bcdverfication\Bcdverfication\froma-2.aspx.cs:370
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +11594516
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +274
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1890

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4110.0
```

Answer (score 5):

**"An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request"** means this error has no programming to "handle" error correction and display a friendly error message.

**"Stack Trace"** is a detailed technical message intended for the programmer to locate where the program failed. It is the default error message for "unhandled errors" and a bug if displayed to the end user.

**"SqlException"** means the error was reported by the database part of the application.

**"String or binary data would be truncated."** means the database was asked to save text longer than the target database field. Maybe the field is limited to 100 characters but was asked to save 110 characters. The last 10 characters would not fit, and the result would be shortened or 'truncated' unexpectedly.

**"The statement has been terminated"** means the program
has stopped to report the error rather than saving an incomplete portion. It is annoying, but better than silently losing data.

**"Bcdverfication.froma_2.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)"** is the name of the function handling the button-click event that posted the form to the database (usually named the same as the button itself).

**"C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\Bcdverfication\Bcdverfication\froma-2.aspx.cs:370"** is the name of the csharp application file the programmer should look at, starting with line 370.

**In summary:**
A field on the web form is allowing too much text to be entered in one or more fields, but no helpful error is displayed until the button is clicked to send it to the database that properly complains in a most unhelpful way.

I hope that helps you locate the cause of the issue.